# Fullcalendar 3.0 Display error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

Here is a screen: [draw error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDirQ.png).

My problem is that the single events are drawed over 2 days.
If I click on week mode the events are drawed, on day mode not. 
If I click on previous/ next the calendar return "**Cannot read property 'event' of undefined**" and the existing events disappear.

When I click on empty day, fullcalendar sometimes return "**Cannot set property 'el' of undefined**".

Here is some source.

Include:
 - jQuery.js
 - bootstrap.js /css
 - moment.js
 - fullcalendar.js /css

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

<script>
        $(window).load(function() {
            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultView: 'month',
                locale: 'de',
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                editable: true,
                allDaySlot: false,
                allDayDefault: false,
                eventOverlap: false,

                events: "./kalender/events.php",
            });
        });
</script>
```

events.php return an json array.

```
[{"start":"2017-02-03T12:00:00+0100","id":7,"titel":"test","nachricht":"nachricht","overlap":false,"color":"rgb(255,0,0)"},{"start":"2017-02-05T12:00:00+0100","id":8,"titel":"Bf1 Key","nachricht":"test","overlap":false,"color":"rgb(255,0,0)"},{"start":"2017-02-10T00:00:00+0100","id":9,"titel":"asd","nachricht":"asdasd","overlap":false,"color":"rgb(255,0,0)"},{"start":"2017-02-17T00:00:00+0100","id":10,"titel":"sdf","nachricht":"sdf","overlap":false,"color":"rgb(255,0,0)"}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue, using your same code: https://jsfiddle.net/917c0mwr/

Comment: this is so strange! 
Here is my full source code.
http://pastebin.com/WBdqf13P
(exact the same..)

Comment: I can't access pastebin from my job...but I think that maybe you have some version issues...check the version of the libraries that I use on my jsfiddle against yours :)

Comment: thank you verry mutch! Something in my files is broken. If I use your cdn all works fine.! Thanks

Comment: I'm glad to help Alex :)

Comment: how can i display the title of an event and not the time? (e.g. 12p, 12am..)

Comment: On your php file just change `titel` for `title`, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/917c0mwr/1/

Comment: yeah i did, but I mean without "time pm/am"... :)

Comment: Just add `timeFormat: 'H:mm',`... demo: https://jsfiddle.net/917c0mwr/2/